# How to change stack view orientation depending on device orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For Ipads with size class regular-regular for both device orientations portrait/landscape I want to force a stack view to be

```
horizontal if device is in portrait mode
vertical if the device is in landscape mode
```

Though I can set the stack view orientation in the story board for R:R, I cannot set it depending the portrait/landscape mode.
How can I achive this?

Comment: Listen for the "view will change size" event and use the horizontal/vertical ratio to know which orientation we are in.

Comment: I've made a few attempts but with no luck. Setting the stack views axis in viewWillLayoutSubviews method doesn't seem to work. What do you mean with the "will change size" event exactly?

Comment: I mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in UIViewController method which does this. "stack" below is the stack view:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: 
UITraitCollection?) {
    if view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
        stack.axis = .horizontal
    } else {
        stack.axis = .vertical
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't listen to the question. On iPad, there is no change in trait collection size class on rotation.